# Fast way to get common items of two ordered iterables?

Tags: java, guava, apache-commons, iterable

How do I get common items of two **ordered** iterables ? Is there any library method from apache commons or Guava or any such library that does it using a fast algorithm ?

Comment: have you seen new for loop that uses lambada expression in Java 8 ?

Comment: No idea about that.. btw I'm not using Java 8 yet.. I am on java 7

Comment: take a look at it,you may find it interesting

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your elements are comparable:

```
List<E> res = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator<E> it1 = orderedIterables1.iterator();
Iterator<E> it2 = orderedIterables2.iterator();
if(!it1.hasNext() || !it2.hasNext()) { // is one of the iterables empty?
    return res;
}
E e1 = it1.next();
E e2 = it2.next();
while(it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {  // go through each iterable
    int c = e1.compareTo(e2);
    if(c == 0) {
        res.add(e1);
        e1 = it1.next();
        e2 = it2.next();
    } else if(c < 0) {   // e1 is lesser than e2, so take next e1
        e1 = it1.next();
    } else {             // e2 is lesser than e1, so take next e2
        e2 = it2.next();
    }
}
// one of the iterables has now been exhausted 
int c = e1.compareTo(e2);
if(c < 0) {
    while(c < 0 && it1.hasNext()) {  // while e1 < e2, let's take the next e1!
        e1 = it1.next();
        c = e1.compareTo(e2);
    }
} else if(c > 0) {
    while(c > 0 && it2.hasNext()) {  // while e2 < e1, let's take the next e2!
        e2 = it2.next();
        c = e1.compareTo(e2);
    }
}
if(c == 0) {
    res.add(e1);
}
```

Comment: I disagree : ``List(4)`` and ``List(1,2,4)`` does not even enter the loop. ``List(1,4)`` and ``List(1,2,4)`` does but you need to add ``4`` to the result.

Comment: typo : `E e1 = it1.hasNext();` -> `E e1 = it1.next();` (same for `E e2 ...`)